# AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'createLBPHFaceRecognizer' in python 3.6.4 and opencv 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, opencv, opencv3.0

I used different types of things and I need this to work in 3.6 Python. i also try
roc = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create() but getting the same error but this time with face module. Need help.

The same code is working in python 2.7.13, opencv 2.4.10.

How to make it work in python 3.6 and opencv 3.4.
I am working in a windows environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have the opencv-python package installed instead of the opencv-contrib-python package. A lot of the proprietary algorithms were removed from the main OpenCV repository when OpenCV came out and put in the contrib repository.

Try switching versions.